# Getting data from Redux on every component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to learn Redux and I just wanted to clarify some things,

Suppose I have a component which renders multiple level's of **words** to learn, let's call it the **Main component**.

Suppose that in the main component, I am fetching 100 words and I render 10 levels which include 10 words each.

Now, I want to go to a level by clicking on it, and see its words, this will be a new **component** called **Level**.

**My question is** that in order to access the words array, I need to connect both the Main and Level components to the Redux store, so what if I need multiple components besides these both that needs to access the words array?

Do I need to connect every component to the store every time?
What about optimization?

Comment: can we have some code please.. so i can see and help..  lets know where you're having the issue..

Comment: there isn't any issue, I just wanted to understand how it works.

Comment: you know its easier if you've tried and then you had an issue somewhere, so i could actually assist you.. and it would help me explain better, because there's soo much to it. except i send you links to resources.